# When the Test Ran in Distribution Mode creating 2 JTL & 2 View Results Tree files

Tags: jmeter

I have executed the Distribution for 1500 Users with 5 Salve Machine with the below Design.

Test has created 2 JTL files , 2 Active Threads Overtime CSV & 2 View Results Tree CSV files with different data. I am not able to figured out why?
In order to get all the Sample Data into 1 JTL file , 1  Active Threads Overtime CSV & 1 View Results Tree CSV file do I need to do set configuration anywhere to get all the rows in file?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be using any [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), it's sufficient to just run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and specify the desired .jtl output path via [`-l` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

something like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -R slave1,slave2 -l /path/to/result.jtl
```

JMeter slaves send results back to master, it collects metrics and stores it into a single .jtl results file which you can later analyze using Listeners or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) or whatever.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)